# I am not getting the results as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display the results according to the option select from the list but not getting the result.I want when I click on "option 1" then "answer 1" will appear and other answers will be hidden, and as I select "option 2" then "answer 2" shows and else all answers will be hidden and so on...

```
HTML:

<div id="amenities" target="1">option 1</div>
<div id="amenities" target="2">option 2</div>
<div id="amenities" target="3">option 3</div>
<div id="amenities" target="4">option 4</div>
<div id="amenities" target="5">option 5</div>
<div id="amenities" target="5">option 5</div>

<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 1</div>
<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 2</div>
<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 3</div>
<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 4</div>
<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 5</div>
<div id="list" class="amenities-list">answer 6</div>

JQuery:

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#amenities').click(function(){
        jQuery('.amenities-list').hide();
        jQuery('#list'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});

CSS:

.amenities-list{display: none;}
```

Comment: The `id` attribute on a DOM element should *really* be unique..

Comment: @MikeChristensen you mean I have to change the answer id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit div ids by adding number to them. also change the id of options to class.

```
<div class="amenities" target="1">option 1</div>
<div class="amenities" target="2">option 2</div>
<div class="amenities" target="3">option 3</div>
<div class="amenities" target="4">option 4</div>
<div class="amenities" target="5">option 5</div>
<div class="amenities" target="5">option 5</div>

<div id="list1" class="amenities-list">answer 1</div>
<div id="list2" class="amenities-list">answer 2</div>
<div id="list3" class="amenities-list">answer 3</div>
<div id="list4" class="amenities-list">answer 4</div>
<div id="list5" class="amenities-list">answer 5</div>
<div id="list6" class="amenities-list">answer 6</div>
```

and edit your jquery to get class:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.amenities').click(function(){
        jQuery('.amenities-list').hide();
        jQuery('#list'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am trying to get the results as when I click option 1 the JQuery trigger a function and add a clicked option attribute to #list so the answer can show on screen hope you get my point.

Comment: You don`t need more attribute to show answer. the current code - show() - is enough. What do you mean from showing answer on screen?